# How to make a loop script for Google sheet?

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wanted to have a script that will change text to a hyperlink using script. I have column D in Google sheet from D1:D, for example:

```
12346
34566
23456
23455... and so on...
```

Currently, I'm using this script, this is for a specific tab named `Sheet1` only.

```
function makeLink() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    var aCell = ss.getRange("D1"), value = aCell.getValue();
    aCell.setValue('=HYPERLINK("https://sellercentral.amazon.com/hzefad/orders/&orderId='+value+'","'+value+'")');  
    var aCell = ss.getRange("D2"), value = aCell.getValue();
    aCell.setValue('=HYPERLINK("https://sellercentral.amazon.com/hzefad/orders/&orderId='+value+'","'+value+'")');  
    var aCell = ss.getRange("D3"), value = aCell.getValue();
    aCell.setValue('=HYPERLINK("https://sellercentral.amazon.com/hzefad/orders/&orderId='+value+'","'+value+'")');  
    var aCell = ss.getRange("D4"), value = aCell.getValue();
    aCell.setValue('=HYPERLINK("https://sellercentral.amazon.com/hzefad/orders/&orderId='+value+'","'+value+'")');  
    var aCell = ss.getRange("D5"), value = aCell.getValue();
}
```

Is there a way to to use looping for me to shorten my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
i = 1
while (true) {
    var range = ss.getRange("D" + i);
    var value = range.getValue();
    if(value == "") {
        break;
    }
    range.setValue('=HYPERLINK("https://sellercentral.amazon.com/hzefad/orders/&orderId='+value+'","'+value+'")');
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! This works perfectly to me Martin!. Thank you. You're the best!

Comment: You're welcome Franc, glad I could help you. Can you please mark the answer as "Accepted" please?